# Javascript/HTML image editor for multi-users

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The idea is simple :
Having an image editor that work like a google doc :
You can see people changes almost instantly

I did some research on internet, I wanted to start with a basic javascript image editor. I'm using this on a html5 game that's not mine (but it allows scripts with GreaseMonkey).

For now I did a button that display and close a window with a google doc inside it : [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/6Pkt3k5y).
But it's not the best image editor at all ^^

I tried to use and understand some codes I've found on google but none of them seems to work.(Replacing the iframe by a canvas) I've even tried to remove the drag option, thinking it could affect the canvas but nope, it's not working.

If you have any good tutorials about javascript image edition and html canvas, I'll love to learn about it.
If you have an idea of why canvas isn't working, I'll be happy to learn about it ^^

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start off:

**Multiple people editing the same object**(image in this case): You will propably need to setup some kind of a P2P stream(Best solution is to use Webrtc + data channels OR *of course* websockets).

Acctuall canvas stuff: Thats just javascript. Any w3schools tutorial should do. I made a small game(using canvas and plain JS). Maybe you can use for quick reference(just read it trough and try to understand whats happening) : https://github.com/IvRRimum/agario-duel-webrtc

That should get you started.

Comment: I think I'll find a way to work around with this, your small game helped me with canvas, and I've found lots of usefull Webrct tutorials.

I Don't like w3shools cause it's not big examples (as your game)